# Sort by values of array of documents in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called collection. Each Object document has a nested array of documents called keyword.

I want to sort documents using key **3d032a58-476c-4639-8d61-1bbc7ccb3e16** in all documents

```
{
"keyword": [
    {
        "3d032a58-476c-4639-8d61-1bbc7ccb3e16": [
            "4",
            "kb",
            "kilo bytes"
        ]
    },
    {
        "62e2e8fb-567e-4d06-9f80-ee247a578f31": [
            "3",
            "GB"
        ]
    }
       ]
 }
```

Comment: Using dynamic values as keys is considered bad design practice, can you change your schema design?

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution

```
db.collection.find({
 $query:{},
 $orderby:{"keyword.e1f76b6a-0b12-4eb3-9627-4ce220f86fca.0":-1}
}
```

will sort my documents in descending order for the values of key **e1f76b6a-0b12-4eb3-9627-4ce220f86fca**